# I am trying to use pyautogui in a loop to spam my friend's dm's (don't ask why)

Tags: python, loops, pycharm, pyautogui

I have recently installed pyautogui and it all seems to be working perfectly. I want to spam my friend's dm's and therefore use command, a, c and then v. It all works completely fine if I type: pag.hotkey('command','v') many times to make it make a big message. However, I tried using for loop and also tried while loop but it does not seem to execute anything inside the loop. This means it will select the text I have written to be spammed, copies it but as the paste line is in the for loop it does not execute and therefore does not paste it over and over again. All loops seem to not work when I use pyautogui. I use PyCharm by the way.

````
pag.typewrite("jelly",0.1) #enters the text
pag.hotkey('command','a') #selects the text
pag.hotkey('command','c') # copies the text
for i in range(10): #should iterate the line indented 10 times
    pag.hotkey('command', 'v') #pastes the copied text
pag.keyDown('enter') #presses down on enter
pag.keyUp('enter')#releases enter key
#should have sent the phrase 'jelly' ten times in one big text```
**I forgot to include import pyautogui as pag at the top because I accidentally cut it off when I copied and pasted my code**
Someone please help me find a way to use loops with pyautogui, it is very annoying.
````

Answer (score 1):

```
pag.typewrite("jelly",0.1) #enters the text
for i in range(10): #should iterate the line indented 10 times
    pag.typewrite("jelly",0.1) #pastes the copied text
pag.keyDown('enter') #presses down on enter
pag.keyUp('enter')#releases enter key
```

Why not just type the phrase jelly 10 times? I see no difference.

Comment: What if I want it 300 times though? I don't want to have to copy out a line 300 times.

Comment: There is no copying involved